# Enable TextWrap in dynamic DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, c#-4.0, wpfdatagrid

I am generating a `DataGrid` dynamically and adding it to a `StackPanel` on my WPF application.

As the is dynamically generated, there is no mark up on XAML side for the same and I need to manage the binding and all properties programatically.

I want my `DataGrid` to have the values in the cell wrapped to the next line if the text is lengthy.  I understand that I need to replace the `DataGridCell` with `TextBlock` and set the `TextWrap` property on it. All the examples that I have found suggest something on those lines itself. However, I couldn't find a way to do it completely from code behind, without XAML.

So far, I have tried to the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();   

dg.ItemsSource = ((DataSet)data).Tables[0].DefaultView;
dg.DataContext = ((DataSet)data).Tables[0].DefaultView; 

DataTemplate ct = new DataTemplate(typeof(DataGridCell));
FrameworkElementFactory tb = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
tb.SetValue(TextBlock.TextWrappingProperty, TextWrapping.Wrap);
ct.VisualTree = tb;

dg.ItemTemplate = ct;
dg.ColumnWidth = 300;
```

Can you please point me to the right direction here?

**[Update]: Solution**

On further researching I was able to get a solution to my issue. For Auto generated columns, we need to capture the  `AutoGeneratingColumn` event and replace the default `DataGridTextColumn` by a `DataGridTemplateColumn` which would have a `TextBlock` in it. And we can then set the `TextWrappingProperty' to get the text wrapped.

Following is the updated code:

```
DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();   

dg.ItemsSource = ((DataSet)data).Tables[0].DefaultView;
dg.DataContext = ((DataSet)data).Tables[0].DefaultView; 

DataTemplate ct = new DataTemplate(typeof(DataGridCell));
FrameworkElementFactory tb = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
tb.SetValue(TextBlock.TextWrappingProperty, TextWrapping.Wrap);
ct.VisualTree = tb;

dg.AutoGeneratingColumn += new EventHandler<DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs>(dg_AutoGeneratingColumn);

dg.MaxColumnWidth = 300;
```

and then the Code under the Event Handler:

```
 private void dg_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
        {
        //cancel the auto generated column
        e.Cancel = true;

        //Get the existing column
        DataGridTextColumn dgTextC = (DataGridTextColumn)e.Column;

        //Create a new template column 
        DataGridTemplateColumn dgtc = new DataGridTemplateColumn();

        DataTemplate dataTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(DataGridCell));

        FrameworkElementFactory tb = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
        tb.SetValue(TextBlock.TextWrappingProperty, TextWrapping.Wrap);
        dataTemplate.VisualTree = tb;

        dgtc.Header = dgTextC.Header;
        dgtc.CellTemplate = dataTemplate;

        tb.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, dgTextC.Binding);

        //add column back to data grid
        DataGrid dg = sender as DataGrid;
        dg.Columns.Add(dgtc);
    }
```

Comment: On further research, I found that I need to capture the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event and apply the `DataTemplate` there. I'm in the process of doing that, but stuck at getting the values bound to the new column types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternate approach is to use a behaviour like this.

```
  public class DataGridWrapTextBehaviour : Behavior<DataGrid>
  {
     private DataGrid DataGrid
     {
        get { return AssociatedObject as DataGrid; }
     }

     private Style ElementStyle { get; set; }
     private Style EditingElementStyle { get; set; }

     protected override void OnAttached()
     {
        base.OnAttached();

        this.ElementStyle = new Style( typeof( TextBlock ) );
        this.ElementStyle.Setters.Add( new Setter( TextBlock.TextWrappingProperty, TextWrapping.Wrap ) );

        this.EditingElementStyle = new Style( typeof( TextBox ) );
        this.EditingElementStyle.Setters.Add( new Setter( TextBox.TextWrappingProperty, TextWrapping.Wrap ) );

        this.DataGrid.Columns.CollectionChanged += Columns_CollectionChanged;
     }

     protected override void OnDetaching()
     {
        this.DataGrid.Columns.CollectionChanged -= Columns_CollectionChanged;
        base.OnDetaching();
     }

     private void Columns_CollectionChanged( object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e )
     {
        foreach ( var column in this.DataGrid.Columns.OfType<DataGridTextColumn>() )
        {
           column.ElementStyle = this.ElementStyle;
           column.EditingElementStyle = this.EditingElementStyle;
        }
     }
  }
```

You can then drap and drop the behaviour onto the DataGrid in Expression Blend.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I must say is that you are using the datagrid in a wrong manner.

```
 dg.ItemTemplate = ct;
```

is a wrong code!

WPF `DataGrid` does not entertain `ItemTemplate` property as other `ItemsControls` do. You would have to supply column templates in `DataGrid` for it to work correctly.

When `DataGridBoundColumn` \ `DataGridTextColumn` columns are supplied to the `DataGrid` , you could set their `ElementStyle` property  like this...

```
        <toolkit:DataGrid
                 AutoGenerateColumns="False">                
            <toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
                <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn 
                         Binding="{Binding SomeProperty}">
                    <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                            <Setter Property="TextWrapping"
                                    Value="Wrap"/>
                        </Style>
                    </toolkit:DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                </toolkit:DataGridTextColumn>
            </toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
        </toolkit:DataGrid>
```

... where `toolkit` is namespace of the WPF toolkit in version .Net 3.5 or prior. In .Net 4.0, its part of the standard `System.Windows.Controls` namespace.

But that exact same solution is a little complicated in your case is because your grid has `AutoGenerateColumns` as true by default that generates the `DataGrid.Columns` automatically. So you have no scope to set this `ElementStyle` property.

So we have to take the XML and code behind approach ...

**XAML:**

```
       <toolkit:DataGrid x:Name="dg">
            <toolkit:DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}"
                       x:Key="WrappedTextBlockStyle">
                    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
                </Style>
            </toolkit:DataGrid.Resources>                
        </toolkit:DataGrid>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
    dg.ItemsSource = ((DataSet)data).Table[0].DefaultView;
    dg.Columns.CollectionChanged
       += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(
              Columns_CollectionChanged);

    void Columns_CollectionChanged(
         object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach(DataGridColumn col in e.NewItems)
            {
                if (col is DataGridTextColumn)
                {
                    ((DataGridTextColumn) col).ElementStyle
                         = dg.Resources["WrappedTextBlockStyle"] as Style;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps...

**Note:** A word of caution that wrapping textblocks make the performance of WPF dataGrid slower.

Comment: yeah, you are right, I did figure, using 'ItemTemplate' isn't the correct way to go.  However, I cant use your approach too as I don't have any thing in the XAML markup for this. Its a dynamically generated control which is appended to the `StackPanel` at runtime.

Comment: Why cant you use this in code debhind. Styles such as `WrappedTextBlockStyle` can be created dynamically in code behind as well. Search google for samples.

Comment: Thanks for your help @AngelWPF, I was already in the middle of another approach and that worked. However, I'd try your approach too sometime. :)